# Run python script using a docker image

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I downloaded a python script and a docker image containing commands to install all the dependencies. How can I run the python script using the docker image?

Answer (score 3):

Copy python file in Docker image then execute -

```
docker run image-name PATH-OF-SCRIPT-IN-IMAGE/script.py
```

Or you can also build the DockerFile by using the RUN python PATH-OF-SCRIPT-IN-IMAGE/script.py inside DockerFile.

### How to copy container to host

```
docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target
```

### How to copy host to the container

```
docker cp /host/local/path/file <containerId>:/file/path/in/container/file
```

Comment: Can you explain how to copy the python file in the docker image?

Answer (score 2):

Run in interactive mode:

```
 docker run -it image_name python filename.py
```

or if you want host and port to be specified:

```
 docker run -it -v filename.py:filename.py -p 8888:8888 image_name python filename.py
```

Comment: Getting this error

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: For this docker run -it image_name python filename.py

Comment: could you please  write down which command were you running on the shell? and attach the error snapshot?

Comment: Command:  docker run -it image_name python filename.py

Comment: Error: WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
/usr/local/anaconda/bin/python: can't open file 'filename.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: ooops... filenane is the file name of your file e.g. myscript.py in the same folder from where you are passing this code on the command prompt (e.g. C:/myfolder/myscript.py)

Comment: Yes, Manoj I replaced filename with my python filename. I cannot share the filename that is why I replaced it in the error message

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

First, Copy your python script and other required files to your docker container.

```
docker cp /path_to_file <containerId>:/path_where_you_want_to_save
```

Second, open the container cli using docker desktop and run your python script.

Answer (score 0):

The best way, I think, is to make your own image that contains the dependencies and the script.

When you say you've been given an image, I'm guessing that you've been given a Dockerfile, since you talk about it containing commands.

Place the Dockerfile and the script in the same directory. Add the following lines to the bottom of the Dockerfile.

```
# Existing part of Dockerfile goes here    
COPY my-script.py .
CMD ["python", "my-script.py"]
```

Replace `my-script.py` with the name of the script.

Then build and run it with these commands

```
docker build -t my-image .
docker run my-image
```

Comment: @RishabGupta If it doesn't work, then please edit your post and add the Dockerfile you've got to it.